# CleverTap integration into react native app

Tags: push-notification, clevertap

After successfully integrating CleverTap into my React Native app and confirming the initialization of the SDK, I encountered an issue upon returning to the CleverTap dashboard. Despite ensuring all necessary fields are correctly configured, the dashboard consistently prompts to 'continue with the checklist first.' It appears that the CleverTap SDK initialization is not effectively linking the app with the CleverTap dashboard. I require assistance in resolving this matter.

[image]